# Does bind() modify sin_port in C?

Tags: c, networking, posix, systems-programming

Does the `bind()` function in linux can modify its argument ? I ask this because a `sin_port` of 0 means that the OS will choose the port, and I would like to get this port after this call.

Comment: This will be covered in the documentation, no? It also works to ask the real question directly: "How to get the port bound with bind() when it's chosen automatically?" If the method is such-and-such-is-modified, then that's the method. And if another method is used, then modification of arguments is not relevant to the task.

Comment: Ok, I miss the `const` modifier in the documentation. Thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not modify the argument. Instead you use `getsockname` after binding to find out what port you got.

You can also use `getsockname` after `connect` to get both the local port assignment *and* the local address (if you have more than one address) correspomnding to the route to the remote host. This works even with UDP where `connect` doesn't actually send any packets and only logically binds addresses.

Comment: Convenient link [man 2 getsockname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html)